# What is the opposite of UI?

Tags: naming

I'm trying to find a good name for a library where I can put in all non-UI related code that I want to share between iOS apps (networking, filesystem, logic, algorithms, data structures). Names that I don't like too much:

- Model
- Backend
- NonUI
- Core

Suggestions?

Comment: What is the opposite of a Dog?  The only logical consistent answer is NonUI.

Comment: I think the problem here is trying to put all non-UI into a single bucket... why put networking and data structures into the same category?

Comment: Application logic is one phrase i've seen for it.  You can also subdivide it further to include Business logic and Backends.

Comment: Try to use Repository maybe :) Application --> Repository then (networking, data structures etc..)

Comment: You're going about this wrong. Name libraries and namespaces after what they do, not what they are.

Answer (score 7):

> a library where I can put in all non-UI related code that I want to share between iOS apps (networking, filesystem, logic, algorithms, data structures)

Don't you think it's a really bad idea?

**The purpose of (1) naming things and (2) having libraries is to make it easier to find things.** By putting unrelated stuff in the same library, you go against this purpose. What's the point in having a library in the first place, and in finding a good name for it? If your colleague asks you: “Where do we have the ETL code?” and your answer is: “Look in the `HugeLibraryForEverything` library”, does the name actually matter?

If you really want to have one and `BigMess` isn't an option (although it's quite representative), `Common` would seem explicit enough, since the purpose is to share code among applications. However, I would strongly recommend to have at least some sort of code organization, and to **have specific libraries for specific purposes**. That networking stuff can go to `YourCompany.Networking`, and `YourCompany.IO` will contain the file system stuff. As for the logic, algorithms and data structures, they would find themselves where they belong to, accordingly to *what they actually do*, instead of being put together just because they *are* data structures or algorithms. Think about it, why would a stream compression algorithm be in the same library as the sorting algorithm?

Once you have a clear structure, finding proper names for the libraries should be a bit less difficult. I won't assert that it's easy, but at least, you wouldn't be in a situation where you search for a name of a bunch of things which have the only common point of *not being something else*.